# PayPal IPN message is always payment - pending

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Working on a sandbox, `Paypal` will always send me back and IPN message with the pair `payment_status:pending`.

I know that this might happen due to different currencies and that I can change settings in my account to accept different currencies.

But, I am using the service when a seller and a buyer that **I don't know** make a transaction, so I can not do anything about it .

1. Is there a way to allow any currency in the POST request ?
2. What really the seller see when the payment status is pending ?
3. If the payment status will change to `completed` later, how will my IPN message look? there is nothing that says how the object from IPN will look when status is changing ? how can I handle such change ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by sending money to the sandbox account and not to my real live account.
So, you must send funds from a sandbox email to another sandbox email.

1. Create another merchant account on the developer website
2. Send money from a sandbox buyer to a sandbox seller